# What is the recognized way to reference accession data (.sra files) from NCBI as a URI?

Tags: phylogenetics, sratoolkit

I would like to assign a URL/URI to accession runs (i.e. SRR IDs) from the NCBI short read archive.

In program listings, I used to list them as `ftp://` URLs, because they were available on their servers as such, e.g. `SRR3418242`:

```
ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR341/SRR3418242/SRR3418242.sra
```

But this approach is deprecated, plus, not all runs are available this way anymore. The now recommended approach is to use [sra-tools to download the data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/docs/sradownload/). This tool takes the SRR Ids directly, i.e. `prefetch "SRR3418242"`, and resolves them to one of many possible locations (home directory, http, etc).

Is there an official URI scheme that can be used to reference accession runs from the short-read-archive ? I would like to disambiguate them from other types of files and URLs (S3 keys, http, file). For file manifests, spreadsheets, and publications, is there something similar to `srr://SRR3418242`?

Comment: No, there isn't something like srr:// and there won't be. ENA via aspera is almost always the preferred way to download data as long as ENA has it.

Comment: Thanks. My concern is the namespace. I'd like to know a nomenclature which doesn't prescribe a particular software or particular read archive. As long as run numbers and sequence data agree on both archives...

Answer (score 1):

The nomenclature is no longer being followed as NCBI is moving all the files to S3/Google cloud. [pysradb](https://github.com/saketkc/pysradb) allows you to fetch the metadata and get the URLs for each individual SRR. See examples in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tOVBg7vPnhTYNjyFQTvN0K9jGT3MyrVb).

You can also download an entire project by doing:

```
pysradb download -p <SRP>
```